# Asymptotical stability of the following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Please consider the following ODE:

$$\dot x = e^t \left( a x^2 + b x \right)$$

for which obviously $x=0$ is an equilibrium point. How can I find the conditions at which the origin is asymptotically stable? What should the Lyapunov function be?

What about an extended version?

$$\dot x = e^t \left( a x^3 + b x^2 + c x \right)$$

where the coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real.

Comment: The first equation can be reduced to a linear DE using $u=a+bx^{-1}$. In the extended case consider the substitution $x(t)=u(e^t)$ so that it becomes autonomous. Discuss the roots and signs of the right side.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you. I don't want to find the roots of the polynomial. Let's suppose that it is of higher order (higher than 5). That is why I was thinking of the Lyapunov theorems. Could you help?

Comment: Around an equilibrium, the stability is in most cases the same as the stability of the linearized system. In this case strike out the higher powers of $x$, the linear coefficient decides the stability, except if it is zero.

Comment: Isn't asymptotic stability a property of equilibria, rather than of ODEs?

Answer (score 2):

Given the system (1st case)

$$\dot{x} = e^{t}\left(a x^{2} + b x\right).$$

Let $a = - \alpha$ and $b = - \beta$, where $\alpha \geq 0$ and $\beta > 0$, then

$$\dot{x} = - e^{t}\left(\alpha x^{2} + \beta x\right).$$

If we choose the Lyapunov candidate function as

$$V = \frac{1}{2} x^{2},$$

then $\dot{V}$ becomes

$$\dot{V} = x \dot{x}$$

$$\dot{V} = - x^{2} e^{t} \left(\alpha x + \beta\right).$$

Since this term $x^{2} e^{t} > 0$ for $x \neq 0$ and $t > 0$, then in order for $\dot{V} < 0$, we must have
$$\alpha x + \beta > 0$$
and therefore, the stability condition can be determined
$$x > - \frac{\beta}{\alpha}$$

If we fix $\alpha = 1$, and the operating range of $x$ is known $\left[x_{\text{lb}}, x_{\text{ub}}\right]$, then $\beta$ can be designed such that it satisfies

$$x_{\text{lb}} > - \beta$$

You should be able to perform the analysis and do the same for the 2nd case.

Comment: The sign of $\alpha$ and thus $a$ doesn't really matter. Only the sign of $\beta$ and thus $b$ matters here for local asymptotic stability (in this case actually also exponential stability).

Comment: Thanks @KwinvanderVeen for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = e^t \left( a x^2 + b x \right)\quad\implies\quad
e^t dt=\frac{dx}{a x^2 + b x}$$
$$e^t=\int \frac{dx}{a x^2 + bx }+c=\frac{1}{b}\ln\left|\frac{x}{ax+b}\right|+c$$
$$\boxed{x(t)=\frac{b}{a+C\:e^{-b\: e^t}}}\qquad C=\text{constant}$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = e^t \left( a x^3 + b x^2+cx \right)\quad\implies\quad
e^t dt=\frac{dx}{a x^3 + b x^2+cx} \quad\implies\quad e^t=\int \frac{dx}{a x^3 + b x^2+cx}$$
$$e^t=\frac{1}{2c}\ln\left|\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{x^2} \right|+\frac{b}{c\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\right)+\text{constant}$$
The inverse function $x(t)$ cannot be written explicitly with a finite number of standard functions. One should be satisfied with the above implicit form of solution.